# porque utilizan el metodo loop_start?

Tags: javascript, html, lista, loops

hola lo que pasa es que no entiendo por que en algunos codigos utilizan loop_start y loop_end para llenar tablas en html por  ejemplo:

```
                <table class="table  table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre del encuestador</td>
                        <td>Fecha de la encuesta</td>
                        <td>Nombre del predio del proyecto</td>
                        <td>Fecha/Hora inicio de grabación</td>
                        <td>Fecha/Hora última grabación</td>
                        <td>Estado</td>
                        <td>Municipio</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--LOOP_START--> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>[#interviewer_name]</td>
                            <td>[#poll_date]</td>
                            <td>[#project_property_name]</td>
                            <td>[#recordStartDT]</td>
                            <td>[#recordEndDT]</td>
                            <td>[#state]</td>
                            <td>[#town_name]</td>
                        </tr>
                    <!--LOOP_END--> 
                </table>
```

por favor me pueden explicar este metodo sobe toodo como implementarlo en javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es para construir dinamicamente el cuerpo de una tabla, por ejemplo:

quiero insertar estos datos `local_data=[2,3,4,5]` en cada fila, te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
            var local_data=[2,3,4,5];
            var table=document.createElement('table');
            table.class="display";
            table.id="example";
            var thead=document.createElement('thead');
            var tr=document.createElement('tr');
            var th=document.createElement('th');
            var texto=document.createTextNode("hora");

            th.appendChild(texto);
            tr.appendChild(th);
            thead.appendChild(tr);
            table.appendChild(thead);
            var tbody=document.createElement('tbody');
            
            for(var indice=0; indice<local_data.length; indice++){//<!--LOOP_START--> 
                var tr=document.createElement('tr');
                var td=document.createElement('td');
                var datos=local_data[indice]; 
                var datoNodo = document.createTextNode(datos);
                td.appendChild(datoNodo);
                tr.appendChild(td);  
                tbody.appendChild(tr);
            }//<!--LOOP_END--> 

            
            table.appendChild(tbody);
            document.getElementById("tabla").appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="ListaUsuarios"></div>
<div id="tabla"></div>
```

Comment: gracias compañero

Comment: @brahian.verac te recuerdo si alguna respuesta ayuda a solucionar tu problema considera marcar +1 y/o marcarla como correcta.